# What's the default connectivity uri for KDE?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I have made the stupid mistake of changing a file and not saving a copy of its previous version. O changed the uri inside of `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf`.

What's the default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I show in my local version of the file on two 20.04 LTS systems:

```
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/
```

Always have backups ...